# Error with cURL and java String variable

Tags: java, string, variables, curl

I'm trying to use glot.io api to compile java code with curl.

I read a text file :

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
```

If I use no quotation marks, I have no problem when I request the url

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Token myToken");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String data =  "{\"files\": [{\"name\": \"main.java\", \"content\": \"" + stringBuffer.toString() + "\"}]}";
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(data);
        out.close();

        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(bf.readLine());
```

But when I use String in my code, the web page return 400 error.
Can you help me ?

Comment: You're generating incorrect JSON. First, you remove all the newlines when reading the text, second, you assume a JSON string value can contain any character, without any escaping necessary. That's wrong. For example, `"` must be escaped. Don't generate JSON by concatenating strings. Use a JSON parser/marshaller library.

Comment: @JBNizet do you know a java JSON librairie ?

Comment: I probably know about 4 or 5 of them. There is plenty of choice. My preferred (but not the simplest) is Jackson.